# Not able to override a Model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, model

I'm working on a module in Magento 2.1 and have to override validate function of this class Magento\Customer\Model\Address

This is what my di.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" type="Mymodule\Module\Model\Address\AbstractAddress" />
</config>
```

and this is what my file contains:

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\Module\Model\Address;

class AbstractAddress extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress
{

    public function validate()
    {        
        $errors = [];
        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($this->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter the first name and last name.');
        }
        return parent::validate();
    }
}
```

But I'm still not able to override the model.

Comment: are you refresh cache.

Comment: @MAK,how to overriding \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override classes which does not injected via DI. This class used only as parent and does not injected in any contructors and does not created via `ObjectManager`.

To override this model you need to create preference on injected subtypes (`\Magento\Customer\Model\Address`, ...).

But preference is not good way to add functionality. You can write plugin on `\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress` and easy solve your problem.

Comment: Problem solved by overriding \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address class as it was inheriting \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress.